# Das Wort „statt“ mit dem Dativ

Tags: preposition, dative, genitive

Dieser Satz steht in meinem Arbeitsbuch (Menschen B1.1):

> *Statt einem Einzelzimmer* habe ich dann aber leider nur ein Doppelzimmer bekommen.

Ich weiß, dass man das Wort *statt* mit dem Genitiv benutzt, aber kann nicht verstehen, warum *einem Einzelzimmer* hier im Dativ steht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Präposition [*statt*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/statt#Pr%C3%A4position) wird standardsprachlich mit dem Genitiv benutzt, bei Pronomen und umgangssprachlich aber auch mit dem Dativ.